# Splitting of Lines in Stern Gerlach Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, spectroscopy

Normally in texts we have read for silver atom for L=0 state, lines split into two parts in Stern Gerlach experiment, discovery of electron spin. What about say 2p state electron for L not equal to zero. Do the lines still split into two parts due to spin or in many parts.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93orbit_interaction

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field $\boldsymbol{B}$ couples to the total angular momentum $\boldsymbol{J} =\boldsymbol{L}+\boldsymbol{S}$ via a term in the Hamiltonian that is proportional to $\boldsymbol{J}\cdot \boldsymbol{B}$.

If there is a non-uniform magnetic field, that roughly points along the $z$ axis, you expect a force (see [this lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/a56c316e4ec548d8bd0a554fac9a74e8_MIT8_05F13_Chap_02.pdf))

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{F} = \mu_z \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial_z} \hat{\boldsymbol{z}} \propto J_z \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial_z} \hat{\boldsymbol{z}} \hspace{6pt}.
\end{equation}

The total number of possible values of $J_z$ (ie the total number of lines you expect to see) is $2J+1$, as pointed out in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/722740/stern-gerlach-experiment#:%7E:text=The%20rule%20for%20the%20total,you%27ll%20see%206%20lines.) by Sean E. Lake.

The possible values of $J$ are constrained by $|L-S|\leq J \leq |L+S|$. For a silver atom $L = 0$ and $S=1/2$, so J is uniquely given by $J = 1/2$ and you expect 2 lines.

If the electronic configuration is more complicated, you need to compute all the possible values of $J$.
If we consider the atom to be in the ground state, $J$ can be determined following a set of rules. You can write compactly your configuration using a [term symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol) ${}^{2S+1}L_J$, as outlined in the Wikipedia page.

For example, antimony has the following electronic configuration $[Kr]4d^{10}5s^{2}5p^{3}$ and its ground state term symbol is ${}^4S_{3/2}$ (see the [NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/antimonytable1.htm) website); consequently, $J = 3/2$ and we expect $4$ lines.